# Any practical way to ensure that data is correctly loaded into database tables?

Tags: java, oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have a Java program that does the following:

1. Parse/Unmarshall XML files
2. Convert them into CSV files
3. Load the converted data into database tables(Oracle)

Each CSV file contains upto a few tens of millons records and is loaded using SQL*Loader.

What would be the best(practical) way to ensure(test) all the data is correctly loaded into the respctive tables?

Comment: If there are no time constraints just load the data back into your application and compare it to your CSV files. Besides that you could try to generate some hash/signature for your data on both sides and compare those. It might still miss some errors though. But why are you concerned the data could get corrupted in the first place?

Comment: I am not concerned about data corruption, but rather data accuracy. I just want to make sure that every element in the XML files is loaded into the right column of the right table.

Comment: In that case wouldn't a simple test be sufficient, i.e. you load in some data that covers all the columns and tables, read it back and check that the result is as expected?

Comment: I agree with @Thomas. Also, you could export your data from the table in `csv` format and then compare the original `csv` with exported one. (although that way you are not checking `xml` to `csv` conversion)...

Comment: If you set-up good constraints in the db then you will just have to check for errors after the program is done inserting.

Comment: maybe fetching the data back from tables to compare with the CSV is the only practical way to ensure data accuracy...

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen the constraints can not tell which XML element(value) should go to which column in the table...

Comment: @d.s Well if your XML has values like and id, name, zip. You can for instance make a constraint for the id that it can only be a integer.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen I understand that, but only doing that can not verify WHERE the value is supposed to be.

Comment: Allright I thought you already had that code and you just needed to make sure everything was in place.